# Compass integration in Intellij Idea 13 via grunt console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, intellij-idea, gruntjs, compass-sass

I have an issue running compass via grunt-task from my Intellij idea 13.1.4

**Environment:**

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit
- node.js: 0.10.29 in /home/lido/.nvm/v0.10.29/bin/node (via nvm)
- ruby on rails: 2.1.2 in /home/lido/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby (via rvm)
- compass: 0.12.7 in /home/lido/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/compass

If use the IDE and select test to run all tests via grunt & karma I get a warning saying:

```
Warning: Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Warning: Couldn't find the `compass` binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH Use --force to continue.
```

Aborted due to warnings.

[image]

I can call compass normally via shell and all works, only not in Intellij idea. If I enable compass support in Intellij settings I have entered `"/home/lido/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/compass"` as executable file. Yet the IDE tells me: "Cannot launch compass executable file"

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?
Thx for your support.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that IntelliJ doesn't recognize the path that is usually (e.g. in your shell) adjusted by RVM.

Check http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/configuring-ruby-sdk.html and http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/rvm-support.html for some pointers on how to get this set up correctly.

Comment: I solved it. The issue was that Intellij was not able to find the executable compass file in my home folder inside rvm although added to path.

Solution:
Simply install the system ruby-compass package by using: sudo apt-get install ruby-compass and add /usr/bin/compass as path for compass executable in intellij. Fixed.